# Where stores Sharepoint 2010 its data in a Groove 2010 Workspace

Tags: sharepoint-2010, groove

Where exactly is the data of a "Groove 2010 Workspace" stored?
On the product page, it says that it will just synced by peer-to-peer, but i can't belive.

I just tried the following:

1. Turn off my PC.
2. Adding file to workspace on my laptop.
3. Turning off my laptop.
4. Turning my PC on.
5. Receiving the new file.

If it will just use p2p to sync, that wouldn't work.

Does anybody knows where my files are actually stored, and how much space you got there?

thanks folks !

P.S. I'm taling about a Groove-Workspace, not a Sharepoint-Workspace on a server

Answer (score 0):

Groove has an internal storage mechanism that is highly secure (encrypted) with a propriety format. Each Groove client is a 'peer', i.e., a client and a server. Therefore, each workspace member has its own copy of the workspace data (files, discussions, forms, etc.). These are stored locally & are hidden.

S.B. Chatterjee
Microsoft MVP - SharePoint Workspace:Architecture